# Let a,b,c,d,m∈Z such that c,d, ≥1 and m>1. Prove or disprove: If a≡b (mod m) and c≡d (mod m), then a^c ≡ b^d (mod m).

Tags: logic

I have been working on this problem for a while now and was wondering if anyone would be willing to assist me with it. I have rewritten this with the definition of the modulo, being that $a-b$ is a multiple of $m (a-b = km$ with $k$ being an integer) and with $c-d$ also being an integer of $m (c-d = lm$ with $l$ being an integer).

If this were to be true, I know that $a^c -b^d$ would also be a multiple of $m$, but I am not sure how to go about proving this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search for counterexamples with small values of $m$.

Comment: Try some example is $2^3 \equiv 7^8 \pmod 5$?  Are you familiar with Fermat's little theorem that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is not a mulitple of $a$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$  That would me $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ but $p \equiv 0$ and $a^0\equiv 1\pmod p$ but $a$ is not nec equiv to $1$.  So Fermat's little theorem shows this is false.

Comment: Oh I am not familiar with this theorem, but will surely look it up! I am familiar with the use of counter examples, but was wondering if the use of a direct proof would also be possible, as coming to a contradiction in the proof would automatically imply the statement is false. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Perhaps the easiest counter example would be $2^4=16\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ but $5^1=5\equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Comment: THis is perhaps beyond your current knowledge but:  If $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime there is some $k$ where $a^k \equiv1\pmod m$ (and, no, $k$ is *not* equal to $m$).  Thus $a^c \equiv a^d$ where $c \equiv d \pmod k$ and *not* when $c\equiv d \pmod m$.  It may be hard at this point to generalize those cases but it is easy to see thay exist.  If we $m=15$ and $a=2$ for istance we get $2^4\equiv 1$ and so $2^k$ will be a repeating sequence of $4$ terms.  And $4$ and $15$ just don't mesh up. $2^{3+15}=2^{2+16}\equiv 2^2$ because the sequence repeats every four terms $\not\equiv2^3 \pmod{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Trying it $2^4\equiv 1\pmod 3$ but $5^1\equiv 2\pmod 3$ so it isn't true.

It's easy to prove that if $a\equiv b\pmod m$ then $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod m$. (we can do induction on $a\equiv a'\pmod m$ and $b\equiv b' \pmod m$ then $ab \equiv a'b' \pmod m$; or we can note that $(a-b)|a^k - b^k$.)

But the premise breaks down with the exponents.  The exponents are not in any way related to modulating by $m$ (subtracting and seeing if the difference is divisible by $m$ will not be reflected in any way be the exponents).

And we will have many cases were this is just false.

In fact... we have Euler's theorem and Fermat's little theorem that are in complete *opposition* to this.

Fermat's Little theorem says if $p$ is prime and $a$ is not a multiple of $p$ then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  That would mean  $a^{k + m(p-1)} = a^k\cdot (a^{p-1})^m \equiv a^k\cdot 1^m \equiv a^k\cdot 1 \equiv a^k \pmod p$.

So **INSTEAD** we have if $a \equiv b\pmod m$ and $c \equiv d \pmod {\color{red}{m-1}}$ and $m$ is prime and $a$ and relatively prime to $m$ then $a^c \equiv b^d\pmod m$, is our result.  $c\equiv d \pmod{\color{red}{m-1}}$ is completely different than $c\equiv d\pmod m$.

(Similarly by Euler's theorem if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then if $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $c\equiv d \pmod{\phi(m)}$ we have $a^c \equiv b^{d}\pmod m$.)